# there is no error in the code but when i click on the button there is no registration on my android database and the data still on the textview

Tags: android, android-button

i made a login and register page , there is no error in the code but when i click on the button there is no registration on my android database and there is no message
i didn't know what is the problem

the main page where i put the registration code

```
   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   DatabaseHelper db;
   EditText e1,e2,e3;
   Button b1,b2;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password2);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.register2);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,loginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
                          }});
           b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            String s1 =e1.getText().toString();
            String s2=e2.getText().toString();
            String s3=e3.getText().toString();
            if(s1.equals("")||s2.equals("")||s3.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fields are empty", 
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {  if (s2.equals(s3)){
                Boolean chkmail = db.chkmail(s1);
                if(chkmail==true){
                    boolean insert =db.insert(s1,s2);
                    if (insert == true){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registred 
           successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"email already 
            exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"password do not 
            match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }});}
            }
```

the databasehelper : i think the problem in the database

```
              import android.content.ContentValues;
               import android.content.Context;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

        import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

      public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
      public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context,"login.db",null,1);
        }

        @Override
          public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
          db.execSQL("create table user (email text primary key,password text)");
        }

          @Override
         public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
          db.execSQL("drop table if exists user");
           }

         public boolean insert(String email,String password){
         SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();
         ContentValues contactvalues = new ContentValues();
         contactvalues.put("email",password);
    contactvalues.put("password",password);
    long ins = db.insert("user",null,contactvalues);
    if (ins==-1)
        return false;
    else return true;
}
public Boolean chkmail(String email){
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from user where email=?",new String[]{email});
    if (cursor.getCount()>0)
        return false;
    else return true;
}
//check email and password
public boolean emailpassword(String email,String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from user where email=? and password=?",new String[]{email,password});
    if (cursor.getCount()>0)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
  }
```

and this is for the login code

```
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class loginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   EditText e1,e2;
   Button b1;
   DatabaseHelper db;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
    e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);
    b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            String email =e1.getText().toString();
            String password =e2.getText().toString();
            Boolean chkemailpass=db.emailpassword(email,password);
            if( chkemailpass==true)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," successfully Login", 
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"wrong email or 
            password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
            });}}
```

Comment: `there is no error in the code` there's a difference between code which compiles, and code which works as it logically should :) while your code might be executing, it isn't doing what it should, and for that you can definitely debug it. add breakpoints, logs, write smaller methods and see if they do what you think they should, etc.

Comment: furthermore, what is `s1` ? `e1`? `b1,b2;`? your variables/code isn't descriptive and this already makes it exponentially harder to debug. take 5 seconds to write a variable name which actually means something and you (and someone else) will be grateful for it later. would you like to open a project where you have to figure out what random letters mean all day ? (Clean code rant)